# Can't build Botan with Clang

Tags: c++, clang, osx-mavericks, botan

I'm trying to build a library that links to Botan 1.11. I used configure.py to generate an amalgamation and included that on my project.

The problem is that when I try to build the project I get the following error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.0/include/wmmintrin.h:30:3: error: "AES/PCLMUL instructions not enabled"
# error "AES/PCLMUL instructions not enabled"
  ^
/Users/me/Projects/Assorted/something/lib/datatypes/botan_all.cpp:8975:28: error: use of undeclared identifier '_mm_aeskeygenassist_si128'
   __m128i key_with_rcon = _mm_aeskeygenassist_si128(key2, 0x00);
                           ^
/Users/me/Projects/Assorted/something/lib/datatypes/botan_all.cpp:9056:7: error: use of undeclared identifier '_mm_aesenc_si128'; did you mean '_mm_and_si128'?
      AES_ENC_4_ROUNDS(K1);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to either compile the amalgamation with the needed CPU flags for AES-NI support (-maes) or disable AES-NI in the configuration step (--disable-module=aes_ni).